disable button on error multiple times in react js
I am trying to disable a button based on validation error on click. if any change on the form input field the button should be enabled, till here is working for me. but when I click next if I get error again the button should get disabled but can't seem to achieve it. So, works fine first-time button click but does not work second time since authFailed has error. can someone please help me to solve this problem?
**Below are the conditions I am using :** 
let disableButton=false;
let existingError=false;
    
const authFailed=hasError(AUTH_FAILED);
    
if (authFailed && !existingError) {
   disableButton=true;
} else {
   disableButton=false;
}
if (authFailed) {
   existingError=true;
}
    
**Input Field:**
<Input fieldName="Name" value={value} onChange={()=>{disableButton=false;}} />
    
**Button:**
<button onClick={() => {
    existingError = false;
    onButton();
  }}`enter code here`
  disabled={disableButton}
  isLoading={false}
/>


You should be using state for disableButton and existingError, not regular variables.

How about this?


const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({inputText: "", isButtonDisabled: false});

    const onChangeInput = (e) => {
        //set new text and unset button disabled flag
        setState({
            isButtonDisabled: false,
            inputText: e.target.value
        })  
    }

    const onClickButton = () => {
        //... perform validation
        const isValidationError = true;
        //disable button on NOK result
        setState({
            ...state,
            isButtonDisabled: isValidationError 
        })
    } 

    return <div>
        <input value={state.inputText} onChange={(e)=>onChangeInput(e)}/>
        <button disabled={state.isButtonDisabled} onClick={() => onClickButton()}>sample button</button>
    </div> 
};

const domNode = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domNode);
root.render(<App />);
<div id="root" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



